# user control numeric pad

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

i had made a user control numeric pad in **wpf**. i want to know when i placed  a control over the form. when i pressed any numeric button then it should be entered in the focused area. how to do it
this is my xaml script
`enter code here`

```
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Name="btn2" Content="2" Focusable="False"  FontSize="26"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row=" 1" />
    <Button Name="btn1" Content="1" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="DarkGray"  BorderThickness="4,2,2,8"  />
    <Button Name="btn3" Content="3" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn4" Content="4" Focusable="False"  FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn5" Content="5" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn6" Content="6" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn7" Content="7" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn8" Content="8" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn9" Content="9" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   />
    <Button Name="btn0" Content="0" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn00" Content="00" Focusable="False" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn_dot" Content="." Focusable="False" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    <Button Name="btn_temp1" Content="Button" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Name="btn_temp2" Content="Button" Focusable="False" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Name="btn_temp3" Content="Button" Focusable="False" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
</Grid>
```

``

Answer (score 1):

You should attach an event handler to the [`UIElement.PreviewKeyDown` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle key presses in WPF in your `UserControl` constructor, or `Loaded` event handler:

```
PreviewKeyDown += YourKeyEventHandler;
```

...

```
private void YourKeyEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something here with e.Key (the pressed key)
}
```

You can find out more from the linked page on MSDN.

Comment: i could not understand completely. please tell me in details. how to add the above events you told and it will also helpful for me if you tell me in vb

Comment: Sorry, I don't write Visual Basic, you'll have to use an online C# to VB converter. As for detail, I don't really know what more I can say... just attach an event handler to your `UserControl` as I have shown you above. If you really don't know how to attach an event handler, then I'm sorry but you shouldn't be using Stack Overflow, as it assumes that its users have some basic understanding of development.

Comment: ok then just tell me what is PreviewKeyDown += YourKeyEventHandler its meaning and where i have to write it.

Comment: That is simply the shorthand notation for attaching an event handler method (`YourKeyEventHandler`) to an event (`PreviewKeyDown`).

Comment: but i did not get how will i get the focus control to add the key pressed in yourkeyeventhandler